# How to create a variable in Matlab where certain subjects are coded as 1?

Tags: matlab, variables

I want to create a variable called 'flag_artifact' where certain subjects from my dataset (for whom I know have bad quality images) are coded as e.g., 1. My dataset is stored in a table T with a certain number of rows and 'subject' is the 1st column in the table.

I managed to do it by creating a for loop. Surely there is a more efficient way to do this by perhaps directly creating the variable and using less lines of code? Could anyone give some advice?

Thank you very much! Here is what I have:

```
flag_artifact = {'T_300'};    %flagging subject number 300 for example


for i = 1:size(T,1)
  if isequal(table2cell(T(i, 1)), flag_artifact)
  T(i, 1) = {'1'};
  end 
end
```

However, when creating the variable flag_artifact = {'T_300'}, I would like it to include more than one subject. I tried using flag_artifact = {'T_300'}; {'T_301'}, as well as flag_artifact = {'T_300', 'T_301'} but it doesn't work because these subject identifiers do not get replaced with 1s.

Comment: Can the cell `flag_artifact` contain more than one value? Is `T1` sorted? I.e. is `T1(2,1) = T_2, T1(300,1) = T_300` and so on? Can you show the first few rows of `T` and `T1`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. It's likely you just need some variation on `idx = ismember( T1(:,1), {'T_300'} ); T(idx,1) = {'1'};`

Comment: What I want flag_artifact to be is a variable that contains several subjects coded as 1 or as flag_artifact. Subjects are arranged in a table T1, apologies if I was not clear. 

What works until now is the following:


`flag_artifact = {'T1_300'}; 
for i = 1:size(T1,1)
  if isequal(table2cell(T1(i, 1)), flag_artifact)
  T1(i, 1) = {'1'};
  end 
end;
idxRemove = ismember(T1.subject,'1');
 T1(idxRemove,:)    = [];`

Is there a way to specify multiple subjects above, rather than just one? I tried  e.g., {'T1_300'; 'T1_301'} but it didn't work - the values were not changed to 1s.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify things, code in comments is not readable.

Comment: @StewieGriffin @Wolfie this solution worked with multiple subjects being specified, which is what I wanted to achieve for efficiency.



`flag_artefact = ismember(T.subject,{'T_001', 'T_051', 'T_300','T_540'});
T.subject(flag_artefact)={'1'};
idxRemove = ismember(T.subject,'1');
T(idxRemove,:)    = [];`